# Not working with saving data to sql server in live WebSite

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am deploy a Website to Live domain..

My Problem is that when I run the application from localhost, It saves the data into the database successfully. But when insert the data from the live site, it does not insert the data into SQL server, but with no error..

But when I run the application with the live database from localhost, it runs successfully..

I already matched the database with local and server.. All are set..
Can anybody help me out???

Comment: I think your have placed the click code inside try catch block. that's why you are not getting any sql exception.
Also match sql db in web config.

Comment: When I run the application with server connection string it's working fine.. it does not take in catch exception..

Comment: OK. Why don't you debug the application on server and check whats going on click code